# Title over align columns

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

Using the `align` environment I have two columns, one for derivation, and another for the rule that was used to create the derivation. However I'm pretty sure that there's a better way to do this?

Here is what I came up with:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \begin{align*}
D&erivation\; &&Rule\\
S&\implies aA& S&\rightarrow aA\\
&\xRightarrow{i-1} a^iA&A&\rightarrow aA\\
&\implies a^ibB&A&\rightarrow bB\\
&\xRightarrow{j-2} a^bb^{j-2}B&B&\rightarrow bB\\
&\implies a^ibb^{j-2}b&B&\rightarrow b\\
&=a^ib^j
\end{align*}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Hello! +1 for a well-stated question! I just added 3 lines to your code, so that it is a full [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Open [the revision history](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/102642/revisions) to see the changes I've made ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since your example shows that you're putting this table into an itemized list,
i'd guess that you want the list header to be on the same line as the item bullet.
you can do this with `aligned`, though you have to explicitly indicate math.
i'd also force the double arrows to the same length (using phantoms) and
add some explicit spacing to make it look nicer:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item  $\quad\begin{aligned}[t]
&Derivation\; &&Rule\\
S&\xRightarrow{\hphantom{j-2}} aA& S&\rightarrow aA\\
&\xRightarrow{i-1} a^iA&A&\rightarrow aA\\
&\xRightarrow{\hphantom{j-2}} a^ibB&A&\rightarrow bB\\
&\xRightarrow{j-2} a^bb^{j-2}B&B&\rightarrow bB\\
&\xRightarrow{\hphantom{j-2}} a^ibb^{j-2}b&\qquad B&\rightarrow b\\
&=a^ib^j
\end{aligned} $
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the biggest obstacle are the differently sized relation symbols in the Derivation block. I would settle with a tabular, the last variant in this code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}

\begin{document}
original
\begin{align*}
D&erivation\; &&Rule\\
S&\implies aA& S&\rightarrow aA\\
&\xRightarrow{i-1} a^iA&A&\rightarrow aA\\
&\implies a^ibB&A&\rightarrow bB\\
&\xRightarrow{j-2} a^bb^{j-2}B&B&\rightarrow bB\\
&\implies a^ibb^{j-2}b&B&\rightarrow b\\
&=a^ib^j
\end{align*}

slightly simplified
\begin{align*}
  & \textrm{Derivation}             &   & \textrm{Rule}\\
S & \implies          aA            & S & \rightarrow aA\\
  & \xRightarrow{i-1} a^iA          & A & \rightarrow aA\\
  & \implies          a^ibB         & A & \rightarrow bB\\
  & \xRightarrow{j-2} a^bb^{j-2}B   & B & \rightarrow bB\\
  & \implies          a^ibb^{j-2}b  & B & \rightarrow b\\
  & = a^ib^j
\end{align*}

with \textbackslash{}alignat
\begin{alignat*}{4}
  & \rlap{\textrm{Derivation}} &&               &\qquad\qquad&   & \clap{\textrm{Rule}}\\
S & \implies                   && aA            &            & S & \;\rightarrow\; & aA\\
  & \xRightarrow{i-1}          && a^iA          &            & A & \;\rightarrow\; & aA\\
  & \implies                   && a^ibB         &            & A & \;\rightarrow\; & bB\\
  & \xRightarrow{j-2}          && a^bb^{j-2}B   &            & B & \;\rightarrow\; & bB\\
  & \implies                   && a^ibb^{j-2}b  &            & B & \;\rightarrow\; & b\\
  & =                          && a^ib^j        &            &   &                 &
\end{alignat*}

with a tabular\\[5pt]
\begin{tabular}{r@{\extracolsep{.5em}}c@{}l@{\extracolsep{10em}}r@{\extracolsep{0.5em}}c@{}l}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Derivation}             & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Rule}\\
  $S$ & $\implies$          & $aA$           & $S$ & $\rightarrow$ & $aA$\\
      & $\xRightarrow{i-1}$ & $a^iA$         & $A$ & $\rightarrow$ & $aA$\\
      & $\implies$          & $a^ibB$        & $A$ & $\rightarrow$ & $aA$\\
      & $\xRightarrow{j-2}$ & $a^bb^{j-2}B$  & $B$ & $\rightarrow$ & $bB$\\
      & $\implies$          & $a^ibb^{j-2}b$ & $B$ & $\rightarrow$ & $b$\\
      & $=$                 & $a^ib^j$       &     &               &
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]